# Salesforce/Apex, date format used by the current user

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

With Salesforce Apex, how do I find the date format used by the current user? I would like to know if the person sees their dates as MDY, DMY, etc.

Comment: I don't have the date in SF, only a token value that is sent to another system. I want to include info on how to display the date to the user. This developerforce [link](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Automatically-format-date-depending-on-users-locale-setting/td-p/198689) entry has a huge if/else that kind of gets what I'm looking for. I was hoping SF would just provide the format because it obviously knows it in order to display the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from another similar question:
Use format method in apex to achieve it.
something like `Date.format('dd/mm/yyyy')`

you can create a map to hold locale as key and format as value and then this map can be used to find the correct date format on runtime.
Use `UserInfo.getLocale()` to find current users locale.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To see the date format of your company instance, you can just use `date.format()` - on any date field

It will give you the date format set in your salesforce instance.

other than that you can use `Userinfo.getlocale()` to get the  locale of the current user.

If you want to capture date and time in your VF page with the format just use `System.now.format()`